# Probability of detecting errors in codewords

Tags: probability-theory, computer-networks, error-correcting-codes

I have been struggling with the below question for quite some time, and I don't have a pointer to move forward.

> A certain Error Control Coding scheme using block codes takes an input block (dataword) of 500 bits
>   and appends a 50 bit code to produce a 550 bit codeword which is then transmitted across channel that
>   causes individual bits to flip with a probability of 0.1 independently. The pairwise Hamming distances
>   between all the codeword pairs is so large that the probability of an error occurring that converts one to the
>   other can be neglected, except as follows: two codewords C 1 and C 2 have a Hamming distance of 10, and
>   two codewords C 3 and C 4 have a Hamming distance of 6.
>   Assuming no knowledge about what datawords may be more or less likely to be desired to transmit, what is
>   the probability that a given block transmission will be corrupted by the channel but the error will go
>   undetected by the receiver? You may answer with an expression, but the answer has to be completely
>   numerical (no symbols).

My thought process about this question is that the probability needs to be calculated as such :
Pr(Selecting either C1 or C2) * P(error in C1 or C2) + Pr(Selecting either C3 or C4) * P(error in C3 or C4).
I feel the Pr(error) is given by a binomial distribution of 55CX(0.1)^x(0.9)^550-x where X=10 or 6.

First, am I thinking about the problem correctly  ? If yes , how do i derive the probability of selection of a particular codeword ?

Edit: I don't have the exact source per se, because this question is from a random uni final exam that I found on the internet. I am prepping for my own exam, and came across this question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to credit the original source where you encountered this problem.

Comment: If you found the exam on the Internet, I encourage you to link to it.  In academia, it is good to get into the habit of citing your sources.

Comment: @D.W., I honestly don't remember where I got it from. I will make sure to keep this in mind when I am posting the next question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine, but the question is not fully well-defined (unless I'm missing something).

The general error probability is 
$$\sum_{i} \Pr(C_i\text{ is transmitted})\Pr(\text{error}\mid C_i\text{ is transmitted}).$$
The questions explicitly says that the error probability of all codewords except $C1,C2,C3,C4$ is negligible, so the error becomes:

$$\sum_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} \Pr(C_i\text{ is transmitted})\Pr(\text{error}\mid C_i\text{ is transmitted}).$$

Computing the error probability is easy: if the Hamming distance is $x$, it takes $\lfloor x/2\rfloor +1$ bit-flips (**or more**) to corrupt the codeword, and $x$ bit-flips (or more?) to be undetected by the receiver. You can easily compute that in a similar way to what you wrote, and get a reasonable bound.
However, the question explicitly says that the terms $\Pr(C_i\text{ is transmitted})$ are unknown, yet it requires you to give an exact numerical answer. contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that's the whole question. So I am going to keep this thread alive in the hope that someone can figure the missing part out :)

Comment: Without the distribution of datawords there is no answer. Maybe the question means for the "worst case" scenario, hence take the maximum over $i$ of $\Pr(\text{undetectable err} | C_i\text{ is transmitted})$. This upper bounds the probability of receiver error regardless of the data distribution.

Comment: How could I calculate this upper bound ? Would this mean that the probability of transmitting any of these codewords is 1 ?

Comment: Right, if the worst codeword is transmitted with probability 1, your failure probability is maximized.